# Identify a character and then highlight it in php

Tags: php, html, css

How can I identify the occurance of a particular character in a string and then highlight it in a different color for better visibility as the string is quite long and I need to scroll on webpage from left to right . It is something like:

```
~$ fname=henry&lastname=ford&age=25&dob=11sep86
```

So I want to highlight the `&` with different color and highlight the `fname`, `lastname` with different colors so that it is easier to debug this string.

Comment: you may have a look on [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode()`:

```
$string = 'fname=henry&lastname=ford&age=25&dob=11sep86';

$url = explode('&', $string);
$result = '';
foreach($url as $num => $one){
    $in = explode('=', $one);
    $result .= '<span style="color:green">'.$in[0].'</span>='.$in[1];
    if($num < count($url)-1){
        $result .= '<span style="color:red">&</span>';
    }
}

echo $result;
```

or `preg_replace()`

```
$string = 'fname=henry&lastname=ford&age=25&dob=11sep86';
$result = preg_replace('/(\w+)=(\w+)/i', '<span style="color:green">$1</span>=$2', $string);
$result = preg_replace('/\&/', '<span style="color:red">&</span>', $result);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use strpos("&",$str) to find occurances of symbols in a string.  I'm sure there are other functions that will better suit your needs though.

For displaying you can insert into the string `<span>` objects that will define a color to transform your text into:

```
fname=henry<span class="redText">&</span> ... etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Very quick solution using str_replace():

```
$string = 'fname=henry&lastname=ford&age=25&dob=11sep86';
echo str_replace('&','<span style="color:orange">&</span>',$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could split the text up into single words, then do an in_array():

```
$text = "your & text";
$words = explode(" ", $text);
if(in_array("&") {echo '<span style="color:red">&</span>';}
```

or

```
if (strpos( $text,'&') !== false) {
    echo '<span style="color:red">&</span>';
}
```